# Strange linker error xcode 11.2.1

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

below I give a strange linker error that I am receiving with Xcode 11.2.1 on macOS 10.15.1.

Any thoughts on the error?

Some similar errors reported online suggests this is a problem that can be rectified by completely deleting Xcode and installing fresh.      As far as I know, I only have the developer tools installed. Can someone tell me the complete steps for complete removal of Xcode 11.2.1?
Then I would like to either reinstall Xcode or replace the Xcode developer tools with replacements from homebrew - is that possible?

```
0x1057be198  __assert_rtn + 127
1  0x1057023da  ld::tool::InputFiles::findDylib(char const*, ld::dylib::File const*, bool) + 740
2  0x1056797e4  generic::dylib::File<x86_64>::processIndirectLibraries(ld::dylib::File::DylibHandler*, bool) + 76
3  0x10570369d  ld::tool::InputFiles::createIndirectDylibs() + 307
4  0x1057045a9  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&, ld::Internal&) + 651
5  0x105713016  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 44
6  0x1056a1044  main + 794
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/DDCPPoisson-2019-10-14-174419.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (counter() < 0xffff), function nextCounter, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-520/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 313.
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [bin/DDCPPoisson] Error 1
make[2]: *** [bin/CMakeFiles/DDCPPoisson.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [bin/CMakeFiles/DDCPPoisson.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [DDCPPoisson] Error 2
```

Comment: Is this about the error shown, or about reinstalling Xcode, or about replacing Xcode by Homebrew-installed tools? Please edit to be more specific.